# Can't retrieve data from Azure

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8

I can insert data just fine into my Azure DB but when I try to retrieve it, it just hangs.

I've authenticated the user and set up the endpoints on my mobile service.

Has anyone encountered this?

Here is the code snippet below of my retrieval code:

```
var users = await userTable.Where(u => u.UserId == userId).ToEnumerableAsync();
```

It doesn't make any sense that I can insert just fine but can't retrieve any data.

I'm working with Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Have you tried to use SQL statement query out data? just to determine where is the root cause.